# Inheriting from mutable.Map causes problems

Tags: scala

I'm creating a new class where I inherit from `mutable.Map`:

```
class Env extends mutable.Map[String, Any] {
  var outer = new mutable.Map[String, Any]
  def get(name: String): Any = if (super.get(name).isEmpty) outer.get(name) else super.get(name)
}
```

The error I get is:

```
Test.scala:6: error: method get in trait MapLike is accessed from super. It may not be abstract unless it is overridden by a member declared `abstract' and `override'
```

Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`mutable.Map` is a *trait* whose `get` method is not implemented (ie. abstract).

You should rather extends `mutable.HashMap`. However, keep in mind that maps `get` methods return an Option and not directly the stored value.